# How to Plot Multiple Line chart Using Pandas of Sentiment analysis data stored in csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, sentiment-analysis

I have data set After doing Sentiment analysis which has  1st column(date) and 2nd column(sentiment)

1. 2019-03-19 ,positive 2019-03-19 ,negative 2019-03-19 ,neutral
   2019-03-19, positive 2019-04-19 ,positive 2019-04-19 ,neutral
   2019-04-19 ,positive 2019-04-19 ,positive 2019-04-19 ,positive
   2019-05-19 ,positive 2019-05-19 ,negative 2019-05-19 ,postive
   2019-05-19 ,negative

Here is the DataSet : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jlmuzFi9OS3mBWjgQvQuKGdNzan708R6/view?usp=sharing

I want to Plot 3 graph having positive, negative and neutral as follows

on x-axis  date  and on y-axis no of positive/neg/neutral somewhat like this any suggestion would useful thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to convert the data into grouped counts by day and sentiment type,

```
df = pd.read_csv('path-to-data/raw-Hospital.csv', header=None, 
                 names=['date', 'text', 'sentiment'], parse_dates=['date',])

by_day_sentiment = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D'), 'sentiment']) \
    .size().unstack('sentiment')
```

which will give you the count data,

```
sentiment   negative  neutral  positive
date                                   
2019-03-10         2       13        42
2019-03-11        15       58        81
2019-03-12        11       61        70
2019-03-13         5      158       110
2019-03-14         2      110       182
2019-03-15        11       80       216
2019-03-16         7       58        66
2019-03-17         2       31        53
2019-03-18        11       87       137
2019-03-19         2       24        53
```

and then you can get a line chart as above by plotting on the summary DataFrame,

```
by_day_sentiment.plot()
```

Comment: Thanks helped alot